# PHP Security Advice on $_GET (combining clean URLs with query string)

Tags: php

I am using "clean" URLs like this:

```
http://localhost/controller/action/param
```

I access the parameters with a custom function like this my_get(1), my_get(2), etc...

However there are times where I think I need to combine them with query strings.
For example: If I need parameter values containing paths with several slashes like:

```
http://localhost/controller/action/param?mypath=foo/bar/qux.jpg
```

I do that because it would be a little harder to implement if done with clean URL.

Now my question is, in combining clean URL and with query string, I only intend to allow this character class:

```
[.&=a-z0-9\/_-]
```

I was wondering would there be any security issue with it? Should I disallow certain characters?

Comment: I think you need to worry less about the slashes and characters and more about what you do with that path. What if I changed the path variables to ../../../etc/passwd? Look up path sanitisation

Comment: What are you going to do with the values of the query parameters? Strings don't pose a security risk in and of themselves.

Comment: @Inerdia in the example above, mypath's value will be deleted with unlink();

Comment: @Ashley reading about that, would it be safe to use 
`$f = realpath($_GET['file']);
unlink($f);` instead of plain `unlink($_GET['file']);` ?

How would you check for "hacking attempt" in the example above?

Comment: @IMB: `realpath` is a good start, but you'll also have to validate if the real path is somewhere safe – a subdirectory of wherever you store your data files.

Comment: @Inerdia how do you actually validate if the real path is somewhere safe? This code `if (strpos($_GET['mypath'], 'foo/bar') === false)` will return true if mypath = 'foo/bar/../../etc/passwd' right? Can you give me an example that will generally work? :-)

Comment: Just out of principle, I would never put true paths in any query, clean URLs or otherwise. Instead, you should track the files to be deleted in a database and assign them some sort of unique identifier. Refer to them with this unique identifier when you're doing any sort of file processing (deleting, moving, etc). Now, your links are no longer dependent on your server's file system and you can check permissions easier.

Comment: @SamT actually that's how I do it but I am looking for a quick and secure way (if ever that's possible) so that I don't have to make a special function for each file I like to delete.

For example, instead of making `localhost/controller/delete_action/path_hint/id` where delete_action contains validation and the actual deleting, I was wondering if I could make a general delete function like `localhost/controller/delete_action?path=foo/bar.jpg` safe enough not to access etc/passwd?

But if it's really that dangerous then I'd rather stick to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mind about string formatting, but please validate the path passed... In the example you said: " in the example above, mypath's value will be deleted with unlink();", well, if you don't validate it in worst cases an attacker could delete any file on the filesystem of the server... ;)

So don't bother about validating the string with a regex, but validate the content of the string and make it safe for your environment... :)

Comment: Would this suffice?

`if (strpos($_GET['mypath'], 'foo/bar') === false) die('invalid');`

Comment: depends on what you are trying to do, but that's a start ;)

Comment: You mentioned I shouldn't bother validating with regex, but if I stick to clean URLs and not use any query string then validating with regex would be a good idea or is it still useless?

Comment: To add with clean URLs, for example, I will only allow this: `[a-z0-9\/_-]`